# Laravel Regex match {string} and not contain {string}

Tags: regex

I am having trouble with regex

I need to create a regex to match

```
//www.youtube.com/embed/
```

but not

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/
```

This doesn't work

```
'regex:[\b{//www.youtube.com/embed/}\b]',
```

But I don't know how.

Comment: Simply try this: `^\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used regexpal.com to play around and found that

```
^//www.youtube.com/embed/
```

matches

```
//www.youtube.com/embed/
```

but not

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/
```

Comment: I had to wait 5 minutes before it would let me