# Laravel Regex Match Url with JPG not working

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel, match

I at http://www.regexr.com/ match a regex that needed for laravel 's regex validation.
validate the url end with jpg/gif/png file.

`/(http|https):\/\/(www\.)?[\w-_\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/((([\w-_\/]+)\/)?[\w-_\.]+\.(png$|gif$|jpe?g$))/ig`
[image: 'regex']
But when i put my code, it throw me an `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found` error.

here are my validation rule

```
$rules  = [
            'title'             => 'required|min:3',
            'description'       => 'required|min:3',
            'url'               => 'required|regex:/(http|https):\/\/(www\.)?[\w-_\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/((([\w-_\/]+)\/)?[\w-_\.]+\.(png$|gif$|jpe?g$))/ig',
          ];
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me after removing the `g` modifier.

Comment: @AvinashRaj ,am still hitting the error. i got try find same situation
[on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631655/laravel-regex-match-string-and-not-contain-string), but still hitting error, not sure how the laravel regex validation format/syntax works. still new to it. i red the documentation, nth much explained.

Comment: use start and end anchors in your regex `^(http|https):\/\/(www\.)?[\w-_\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/((([\w-_\/]+)\/)?[\w-_\.]+\.(png$|gif$|jpe?g$))$`

Comment: use a different delimeter say `~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596587/issue-with-laravel-rules-regex-or-operator), Laravel `|` delimiter is conflicting with the regex alternation `|`.

The regex considered in

```
required|regex:/(http|https)...
```

is `/(http`, thus missing the ending delimiter.

Seems you can fix the issue by using (I took the liberty to clean a few things in your regex):

```
'url' => array('required', 'regex:/(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/((([\w\/-]+)\/)?[\w.-]+\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$)/ig')
```

If Laravel is okay with using different delimiters than `/` I'd also recommend using something else (`~` for example) to lighten the forest of `\/`.